# Excel: How to get in array only cells with text starting with "SIM"

Tags: excel

In excel I have column A with some numbers and letters and I would like to extract to a different column all the cells that start with "SIM" (ex, sim 3; sim 4; sim 5) and its correspondent value on column B and column C. I tried different methods using arrays but none worked as you can see the attached link. Link 2 is what I want the result to be.
Thank you very much.

[Code tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJKHp.png)

[Desirable result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckHGm.png)

Comment: *If* that formula could work, you want to put `SIM` in quotes: `"SIM"`

Comment: Use a pivot table with filters.

Comment: I tried with quotes and it was the same result

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a piece of VBA code. Am checking if the string in Col A starts with "SIM", Then I copy Column A, B, C to Column D, E, F
Change the column names as per your requirements

```
Sub findsim()
Dim rowcount As Integer
Dim Checkcol1 As Integer, Checkcol2 As Integer, Checkcol3 As Integer, Targetcol As Integer
Dim currentRowValue1 As String
Dim currentRow As Integer, arow As Integer
Checkcol1 = 1 'Denotes A column
Checkcol2 = 2 'Denotes B column
Checkcol3 = 3 'Denotes B column

Targetcol = 4
arow = 1
rowcount = Cells(Rows.Count, Checkcol1).End(xlUp).Row

  For currentRow = 1 To rowcount
      currentRowValue1 = Cells(currentRow, Checkcol1).Value
      If UCase(Left$(currentRowValue1, 3)) = "SIM" Then
          Cells(arow, Targetcol).Value = currentRowValue1
          Cells(arow, Targetcol + 1).Value = Cells(currentRow, Checkcol2).Value
          Cells(arow, Targetcol + 2).Value = Cells(currentRow, Checkcol3).Value
          arow = arow + 1
        End If

Next
End Sub
```

Edit

For excel formulas
In first target col say D column, paste this

```
=IF(UPPER(MID(A1,1, 3)) = "SIM", B1)
```

In Second target col say E column, paste this

=IF(UPPER(MID(A1,1, 3)) = "SIM", C1)

Note :- You will get blank cells for those which did not have SIM string. you have to manually delete the spaces

Comment: Thanks, Valli. Is there any way of doing this using a formula instead of VBA because this is supposed to run on an iPhone excel later on, which does not support VBA's?

Comment: I have edited.. But you will get blank spaces if 'SIM' string is not available. VBA is the best way, you will not get spaces